# Unsure of what this Drupal module code does

Tags: drupal

I saw the following code in a module; what's happening here:

```
$element['location_settings'] = array(
  '#type' => 'value',
  '#value' => $element['#location_settings'],
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is part of a form. It is a form element called "location_settings" which is of type value. Here is the description of the value type from the [Drupal Forms API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#val).

```
Description: A form value that is internal to the form
and never displayed to the screen.
```

This this code is storing in the form data which will probably be used by javascript and that is not directly seen on the webpage.

Comment: Thanks, any significance to having the # in '#location_settings'?